# Why is the following query illegal in sql?

Tags: sql, database

Why is the query below illegal?

Suppose you had theses tables:

```
Sailors (sid, sname, rating, age),
Reserves (sid, bid, date),
Boats (bid,bname,color)
```

And this query:

```
SELECT S.sname, MAX (S.age)
FROM Sailors as S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically having an attribute with an aggregate function without a group by clause would make no sense when the table is outputted. 
From the example given,

```
SELECT S.sname, MAX (S.age)
FROM Sailors as S
```

Sailor Table:

```
S.sname      S.age
Sam          5
Mike         20
Tommy        100
```

Suppose the output was:

```
S.sname      Max(S.age)
Sam          100
Mike
Tommy
```

The tuple (Sam, 100) would make no sense, because 100 is corresponded with Tommy.

Answer (score 7):

the `MAX` sql function needs to be done on an aggregate.  The correct form of this query is:

```
select sname, MAX(age)
  from sailors
  group by sname
```

Comment: "needs to be done on an aggregate" --- actually not only. If you only have aggregate functions you may not have `GROUP BY`

Comment: Maybe not, but has little value otherwise.

Comment: It depends. In the context of the question - definitely yes (hence I +1d you :-). In general "Summarise all the values in the table" or "Get the greatest value from the table" is a legit request

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid because you don't have a `GROUP BY` , you will get this error:

> Column 'sailors.sname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

To correct, just add `GROUP BY`.

```
    SELECT S.sname, MAX(S.age) FROM Sailors as S GROUP BY S.sname
```